# How to use fields from 2 models in treeview? openerp

Tags: treeview, odoo

I have a tree that has field with many to one relationship with other model,
I want to change in colors of records of an existing tree view based on the value of field in the other model.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `related` field in this scenario:

Like this:

```
'plan_id': fields.many2one(
        'hr_evaluation.plan',
        'Appraisal Plan',
        ondelete='cascade',
        ),
'company_id': fields.related(
        'plan_id',
        'company_id',
        type='many2one',
        relation='res.company',
        string='Company',
        store=True,
        readonly=True,
        ),
```

And then used the `company_id` field.

Comment: in stock.move model 'loc_type':fields.related('location_id','loc_type',type='many2one',relation='stock.location',string='Type', store=True, readonly=True)  and i want to use usage field in stock.location model like this colors="red:loc_type.usage=='inventory'" , but there are an error occurs,

Comment: can you give me more detail what you wann do in folloing code? what is loc_type??

Comment: loc_type is a field that I added to hold the value of location_id.usage value

Comment: I made it by a field function, and then I displayed the field function, Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: Are you know the answer of this question please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15654286/how-can-i-display-log-message-in-openerp-web-client