# How can I display log message in openerp web client?

Tags: logging, odoo

I try to display a message after create a product object that tell user product with product.name is created successful
This is the code:

```
def log_prod(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    product=self.pool.get('product.product').browse(cr, uid, ids)
    self.log(cr, uid, ids , _("Product %s has been created") % product.name , context=context)
    return True

def create(self, cr, uid, data, context=None):
    new_id = super(product_product,self).create(cr, uid, data, context)
    self.log_prod(cr,uid,new_id,context)
    return new_id
```

when I created the product no thing was appeared 


But after that I tried to create an incoming shipment, the log message for the product creation was appeared, how I can display the log message in the product display page after create it?

Comment: Hello, you can used message_post method to show user product created with name

Answer (score 1):

I have had this problem, but this way helped me and is wonderful:
from this [link](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/how-to-display-dialog-box-16506)

Create a module to save messages and show them in form:

```
from osv import osv
from osv import fields
from openerp.tools.translate import _

WARNING_TYPES = [('warning','Warning'),('info','Information'),('error','Error')]

class warning(osv.osv_memory):
    _name = 'warning'
    _description = 'warning'
    _columns = {
        'type': fields.selection(WARNING_TYPES, string='Type', readonly=True),
        'title': fields.char(string="Title", size=100, readonly=True),
        'message': fields.text(string="Message", readonly=True)}
    _req_name = 'title'

    def _get_view_id(self, cr, uid):
        """Get the view id
        @return: view id, or False if no view found
        """
        res = self.pool.get('ir.model.data').get_object_reference(cr, uid, 'osc_integ', 'warning_form')
        return res and res[1] or False

    def message(self, cr, uid, id, context):
        message = self.browse(cr, uid, id)
        message_type = [t[1]for t in WARNING_TYPES if message.type == t[0]][0]
        print '%s: %s' % (_(message_type), _(message.title))
        res = {
            'name': '%s: %s' % (_(message_type), _(message.title)),
            'view_type': 'form', 
            'view_mode': 'form',
            'view_id': self._get_view_id(cr, uid),
            'res_model': 'warning',
            'domain': [],
            'context': context,
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
            'target': 'new',
            'res_id': message.id
        }
        return res

    def warning(self, cr, uid, title, message, context=None):
        id = self.create(cr, uid, {'title': title, 'message': message, 'type': 'warning'})
        res = self.message(cr, uid, id, context)
        return res

    def info(self, cr, uid, title, message, context=None):
        id = self.create(cr, uid, {'title': title, 'message': message, 'type': 'info'})
        res = self.message(cr, uid, id, context)
        return res

    def error(self, cr, uid, title, message, context=None):
        id = self.create(cr, uid, {'title': title, 'message': message, 'type': 'error'})
        res = self.message(cr, uid, id, context)
        return res
```

Create View form XML:

```
<openerp>
   <data>
        <record id="warning_form" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">warning.form</field>
            <field name="model">warning</field>
            <field eval="20" name="priority"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <form string="Warning" version="7.0">
                    <field name="message"  nolabel="1" />
                    <footer>
                        <button string="OK" class="oe_highlight" special="cancel" />
                    </footer>
                </form>
            </field>
        </record>

        <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="action_warning">
            <field name="name">Warning</field>
            <field name="res_model">warning</field>
            <field name="view_type">form</field>
            <field name="view_mode">form</field>
            <field name="view_id" ref="warning_form" />
            <field name="target">new</field>
        </record>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

And at last you can call method every where you need:

```
return self.pool.get('warning').info(cr, uid, title='Export imformation', message="%s products Created, %s products Updated "%(str(prod_new),str(prod_update)))
```

Answer (score 0):

there's no widget for this AFAIK. you should develop your own. You can find a starting point [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11950556/647924)

Answer (score 0):

```
def log_prod(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
        product=self.pool.get('product.product').browse(cr, uid, ids)
        msg=_("Product %s has been created") % product.name
        self.message_post(cr, uid, ids, body=msg, context=context)
        return True

def create(self, cr, uid, data, context=None):
    new_id = super(product_product,self).create(cr, uid, data, context)
    self.log_prod(cr,uid,new_id,context)
    return new_id
```

Like this code try.

Hope this will help you. :)

Comment: Thanks but AttributeError: 'product.product' object has no attribute 'message_post' :S

Comment: I added _inherit = ['mail.thread'] in the Product_product class , but this error "AttributeError: 'product.product' object has no attribute 'message_post'" appear again

Comment: message_post does not exist in mail_thread class in mail module

Comment: I restarted the server , but at searching on this method in mail.thread,I didn't find it.

Comment: This method exits in mail.thread. In addons latest revision number **8998**, module **mail** file **mail_thread.py** line no **912**

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding, I use openerp6.1 :D

Comment: :D, ooooooooooo, we are discussing in wrong direction, then in 6.1 there is no such kind of thing, as you used self.log method, it makes entry in res.log table, you have to develop your own

Comment: Thanks for your efforts :) , I added a button instead of save button that used to save the product and display the msg.

Comment: Hi @user1576199, I need to do same feature in OpenERP7.  As soon as user creates a product a notification message need to be sent to managers.  When a manager is logged into the application, there needs to be a message in  inbox of messages.

Answer (score 0):

```
def message_post(self, cr, uid, thread_id, body='', subject=None, type='notification',
                        subtype=None, parent_id=False, attachments=None, context=None,
                        content_subtype='html', **kwargs):
        """ Post a new message in an existing thread, returning the new
            mail.message ID.
        :param int thread_id: thread ID to post into, or list with one ID;
            if False/0, mail.message model will also be set as False
        :param str body: body of the message, usually raw HTML that will
            be sanitized
        :param str type: see mail_message.type field
        :param str content_subtype:: if plaintext: convert body into html
        :param int parent_id: handle reply to a previous message by adding the
            parent partners to the message in case of private discussion
        :param tuple(str,str) attachments or list id: list of attachment tuples in the form
            ``(name,content)``, where content is NOT base64 encoded

        Extra keyword arguments will be used as default column values for the
        new mail.message record. Special cases:
            - attachment_ids: supposed not attached to any document; attach them
                to the related document. Should only be set by Chatter.
        :return int: ID of newly created mail.message
    """
    if context is None:
        context = {}
    if attachments is None:
        attachments = {}
    mail_message = self.pool.get('mail.message')
    ir_attachment = self.pool.get('ir.attachment')

    assert (not thread_id) or \
            isinstance(thread_id, (int, long)) or \
            (isinstance(thread_id, (list, tuple)) and len(thread_id) == 1), \
            "Invalid thread_id; should be 0, False, an ID or a list with one ID"
    if isinstance(thread_id, (list, tuple)):
        thread_id = thread_id[0]

    # if we're processing a message directly coming from the gateway, the destination model was
    # set in the context.
    model = False
    if thread_id:
        model = context.get('thread_model', self._name) if self._name == 'mail.thread' else self._name
        if model != self._name:
            del context['thread_model']
            return self.pool.get(model).message_post(cr, uid, thread_id, body=body, subject=subject, type=type, subtype=subtype, parent_id=parent_id, attachments=attachments, context=context, content_subtype=content_subtype, **kwargs)

    # 0: Parse email-from, try to find a better author_id based on document's followers for incoming emails
    email_from = kwargs.get('email_from')
    if email_from and thread_id and type == 'email' and kwargs.get('author_id'):
        email_list = tools.email_split(email_from)
        doc = self.browse(cr, uid, thread_id, context=context)
        if email_list and doc:
            author_ids = self.pool.get('res.partner').search(cr, uid, [
                                    ('email', 'ilike', email_list[0]),
                                    ('id', 'in', [f.id for f in doc.message_follower_ids])
                                ], limit=1, context=context)
            if author_ids:
                kwargs['author_id'] = author_ids[0]
    author_id = kwargs.get('author_id')
    if author_id is None:  # keep False values
        author_id = self.pool.get('mail.message')._get_default_author(cr, uid, context=context)

    # 1: Handle content subtype: if plaintext, converto into HTML
    if content_subtype == 'plaintext':
        body = tools.plaintext2html(body)

    # 2: Private message: add recipients (recipients and author of parent message) - current author
    #   + legacy-code management (! we manage only 4 and 6 commands)
    partner_ids = set()
    kwargs_partner_ids = kwargs.pop('partner_ids', [])
    for partner_id in kwargs_partner_ids:
        if isinstance(partner_id, (list, tuple)) and partner_id[0] == 4 and len(partner_id) == 2:
            partner_ids.add(partner_id[1])
        if isinstance(partner_id, (list, tuple)) and partner_id[0] == 6 and len(partner_id) == 3:
            partner_ids |= set(partner_id[2])
        elif isinstance(partner_id, (int, long)):
            partner_ids.add(partner_id)
        else:
            pass  # we do not manage anything else
    if parent_id and not model:
        parent_message = mail_message.browse(cr, uid, parent_id, context=context)
        private_followers = set([partner.id for partner in parent_message.partner_ids])
        if parent_message.author_id:
            private_followers.add(parent_message.author_id.id)
        private_followers -= set([author_id])
        partner_ids |= private_followers

    # 3. Attachments
    #   - HACK TDE FIXME: Chatter: attachments linked to the document (not done JS-side), load the message
    attachment_ids = kwargs.pop('attachment_ids', []) or []  # because we could receive None (some old code sends None)
    if attachment_ids:
        filtered_attachment_ids = ir_attachment.search(cr, SUPERUSER_ID, [
            ('res_model', '=', 'mail.compose.message'),
            ('res_id', '=', 0),
            ('create_uid', '=', uid),
            ('id', 'in', attachment_ids)], context=context)
        if filtered_attachment_ids:
            ir_attachment.write(cr, SUPERUSER_ID, filtered_attachment_ids, {'res_model': model, 'res_id': thread_id}, context=context)
    attachment_ids = [(4, id) for id in attachment_ids]
    # Handle attachments parameter, that is a dictionary of attachments
    for name, content in attachments:
        if isinstance(content, unicode):
            content = content.encode('utf-8')
        data_attach = {
            'name': name,
            'datas': base64.b64encode(str(content)),
            'datas_fname': name,
            'description': name,
            'res_model': model,
            'res_id': thread_id,
        }
        attachment_ids.append((0, 0, data_attach))

    # 4: mail.message.subtype
    subtype_id = False
    if subtype:
        if '.' not in subtype:
            subtype = 'mail.%s' % subtype
        ref = self.pool.get('ir.model.data').get_object_reference(cr, uid, *subtype.split('.'))
        subtype_id = ref and ref[1] or False

    # automatically subscribe recipients if asked to
    if context.get('mail_post_autofollow') and thread_id and partner_ids:
        partner_to_subscribe = partner_ids
        if context.get('mail_post_autofollow_partner_ids'):
            partner_to_subscribe = filter(lambda item: item in context.get('mail_post_autofollow_partner_ids'), partner_ids)
        self.message_subscribe(cr, uid, [thread_id], list(partner_to_subscribe), context=context)

    # _mail_flat_thread: automatically set free messages to the first posted message
    if self._mail_flat_thread and not parent_id and thread_id:
        message_ids = mail_message.search(cr, uid, ['&', ('res_id', '=', thread_id), ('model', '=', model)], context=context, order="id ASC", limit=1)
        parent_id = message_ids and message_ids[0] or False
    # we want to set a parent: force to set the parent_id to the oldest ancestor, to avoid having more than 1 level of thread
    elif parent_id:
        message_ids = mail_message.search(cr, SUPERUSER_ID, [('id', '=', parent_id), ('parent_id', '!=', False)], context=context)
        # avoid loops when finding ancestors
        processed_list = []
        if message_ids:
            message = mail_message.browse(cr, SUPERUSER_ID, message_ids[0], context=context)
            while (message.parent_id and message.parent_id.id not in processed_list):
                processed_list.append(message.parent_id.id)
                message = message.parent_id
            parent_id = message.id

    values = kwargs
    values.update({
        'author_id': author_id,
        'model': model,
        'res_id': thread_id or False,
        'body': body,
        'subject': subject or False,
        'type': type,
        'parent_id': parent_id,
        'attachment_ids': attachment_ids,
        'subtype_id': subtype_id,
        'partner_ids': [(4, pid) for pid in partner_ids],
    })

    # Avoid warnings about non-existing fields
    for x in ('from', 'to', 'cc'):
        values.pop(x, None)

    # Create and auto subscribe the author
    msg_id = mail_message.create(cr, uid, values, context=context)
    message = mail_message.browse(cr, uid, msg_id, context=context)
    if message.author_id and thread_id and type != 'notification' and not context.get('mail_create_nosubscribe'):
        self.message_subscribe(cr, uid, [thread_id], [message.author_id.id], context=context)
    return msg_id
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the easiest way is to use either the "action_info" or "action_warn" client action. They both produce Growl-like notifications, but they use different icons. To invoke either one, return a dictionary from your server action like the following:

```
{
    'type': 'ir.actions.client',
    'tag': 'action_info',
    'name': 'Notification',
    'params': {
       'title': 'Notification Title',
       'text': 'Notification text.',
       'sticky': True
    }
}
```

Most of this should be self-explanatory aside from the `sticky` parameter. `sticky` indicates whether the notification should remain until the user dismisses it. If it's set to `False`, it'll fade away on its own after a few seconds.

There's a somewhat fuller example [on my blog](http://ryepdx.com/2014/12/message-boxes-in-openerpodoo/), if you need one.