# How to create a function for a pop up in OpenERP

Tags: python, odoo

I have created a button in debugging mode of OpenERP and want to display a message on click of that button.

This is the button Ex. then How to write an action on click of this button mainly the popup and message is required

Comment: A good sample to solve this problem is [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15654286/how-can-i-display-log-message-in-openerp-web-client/28260279#28260279

Answer (score 0):

You can write a small wizard to do so.refer to openerp documentation for how to.